# Camel - forceShutdown & rollback

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have route for file processing something like below,

```
fromF("file:in?recursive=false&noop=true&maxMessagePerPoll=10&readLock=idempotent&idempotentRepository=#fileRepo@readLockRemoveOnCommit=readLockRemoveOnRollback=true&delete=true&moveFailed=failedDir")
.onCompletion()
   .process("CompletionProcess")
.end()
.threads(5)
.processe("fileProcess")
.nd();
```

cCurrently when it receives shutdown it waits 45secs and if it's not completed within 45 secs it goes forceshutdown and that time it call onCompletion(CompletionProcess). I have a code to update DB in CompletionProcess and because of that it throws ConfigurationPropertiesBindException as ....ApplicationContext has been closed already. and the file got move to failedDir.

My goal is to stop the route after 45 secs without any roll back, no onCompletion call, and file is as it is in dir.

I am pretty new to camel and trying to understand rollback stragety/shutdown strategy but can't find a solution for above yet. Please guide me.

Thanks!

Comment: your question is unclear, could you tell us how you make the shutdown and share the used code

Comment: 1. when force shutdown occurs, onCompletion was called even though the route was not completed. What needs to be done  not to call onCompletion during forceShutdown?

Comment: OnComplete adds a new route in a separated thread when the Exchange is complete. did you try using two : onCompletion().onFailureOnly() and onCompletion().onCompleteOnly()